# Written text in html exactly outputed?

Tags: html

I was wondering if there is a way of writing text in HTML for example `<p>asdasd
asdasd
asasdasdasd
asdasd</p>`
, and having this exact layout outputed on the page?

I'm pretty sure in JS you can use 
`"""asdasd
asdasda
asdasd"""`
, and that will output exactly that. Is this possible in pure HTML?

Comment: Is the spacing the part that you're hoping to preserve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `white-space:pre;` on the `<p>` element to achieve this:

```css
p {
    white-space:pre;
}
```

```html
<p>asdasd
asdasd
asasdasdasd
asdasd</p>
```

Another possibilty would be to use the `<pre>` element instead of the `<p>` element:

```html
<pre>asdasd
asdasd
asasdasdasd
asdasd</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML entities to do that.
Ref: [Character Entities](https://brajeshwar.github.io/entities/)
for an example, you can write

```html
&lt;p&gt;asdasd<br>
asdasd<br>
asasdasdasd<br>
asdasd&lt;&sol;p&gt;
```

to show

```
<p>asdasd
asdasd
asasdasdasd
asdasd</p>
```